# sql snowflake, aggregate over window or sth

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have a table below

| days | balance | user_id | wanted column |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/08/01 | 10 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022/08/02 | 11 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022/08/03 | 10 | 1 | 1 |
| 2022/08/03 | 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 2022/08/05 | 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 2022/08/06 | 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 2022/08/07 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| 2022/08/08 | 0 | 2 | 3 |

since I'm new to SQL couldn't aggregate over window by clauses, correctly.

which means; I want to find unique users that have balance>0 per day.

thanks

update:
**exact output wanted:**

| days | unque users |
| --- | --- |
| 2022/08/01 | 1 |
| 2022/08/02 | 1 |
| 2022/08/03 | 1 |
| 2022/08/05 | 2 |
| 2022/08/06 | 2 |
| 2022/08/07 | 3 |
| 2022/08/08 | 3 |

---

**update**: how if I want to accumulate the number of unique users over time? with consideration of new users [means: counting users who didn't exist before], and the balance > 0

everyones help is appreaciated deeply :)

Comment: What is the exact output you want here?

Comment: just updated the body, thanks. also, the first table has the *wanted column* as well

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  *,
  COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN balance > 0 THEN USER_ID END) OVER (ORDER BY days)
FROM
  your_table
```

Comment: This counts all users regardless of balance.

Comment: Most databases do not support using `DISTINCT` counts with count as a window function.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen But snowflake apparently does; https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/count.html